# SQL Select expired voucher 7day in month

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM tblvoucher WHERE  Month(tsExpiredDate) BETWEEN Month(tsExpiredDate) AND DATE_ADD(date(NOW()) , INTERVAL 7 day)
```

I follow the step but sql show me output is expire in month. But I need answer output is 7 week expire date in month..Can anybody help me solution?

Comment: To clarify, you want to show expired items between now and 7 weeks in the future or past?

Comment: also, is this mysql or oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Use `INTERVAL`

Expires between now and 7 weeks in the future

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblvoucher 
WHERE tsExpiredDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 WEEK);
```

Expires between now and 7 days in the future

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblvoucher 
WHERE tsExpiredDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: Matt, thank you..yes, this is what i want to show on my sql...Thank you very much :)